# redirect_to(:back) same part of page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a social feed.

If the user scrolls down a lot it is annoying to the user that by liking/commenting he is redirected to the **top of** the page instead of in the same part of the page to where he had **scrolled to**.

Is there any way to do this? Otherwise I'll just use paginate to make the pages smaller, which isn't ideal because that also takes away from user friendliness.

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
    def index
       @activities = Activity.order("created_at desc").where(user_id: current_user.following_ids)
    end

    def show
       redirect_to(:back)
    end
end
```

I've been on a roll with questions please check them out if you have time :)

Comment: Make an AJAX call and you will have no problem at all. :)

Comment: Okay thanks @BroiSatse I added ajax as a tag. I don't know AJAX. That's something I'll need to explore more because I'm finding I'm needing it more in more in my app development process.

Comment: Been there. After some time you will notice even AJAX is not enough. :) It's the time when JS framework come into play. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that is being redirected to the top of the page because the page is being reloaded after a comment/favorite, you could try performing these actions using ajax instead.

This way, the page won't reload and you can modify the DOM to reflect the user's actions with javascript.

Here's some more information on ajax in rails:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

First generate anchors in your page by giving them ids. For example:

```
<div id="activity5">
  ..
</div>
```

Then in your controller, redirect to that part by using an anchor option:

```
redirect_to(request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] + '#activity5')
```

**Note**: `redirect_to(:back)` is the same as `redirect_to(request.env["HTTP_REFERER"])`

Having said that, using Javascript and AJAX is probably a better option.